# How to set up a label default for first time application use

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a label called `totalChips`. It gets the data from being saved so that the player can continue on where they left off. After the first debug the label is empty and then it isn't possible to add chips. I added a button to set the label to 0 but would like the label to be automatically set to zero if there is no value saved. This must be done when the form loads.

````
        {
            if (totalChips.Text == null)
            {
                totalChips.Text = "0";
                Properties.Settings.Default.SaveCoins = totalChips.Text;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
            else
            {
                totalChips.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.SaveCoins;
            }
        } ```
````

Comment: " if there is no value saved" how do you test this? with this nullcheck: `totalChips.Text == null` ? "This must be done when the form loads." there is an event for this. So where and how exactly did you try to set the label text automatically to 0? this part is still not clear to me

Comment: I added a button to set the label to 0 which works and to test if the label can change. The null is to check if the label has a value if not the label should be 0 otherwise the label will get data from the SaveCoins. All this code is under the form_Load event.

Comment: In case you set `Text` to empty in the VS (do you use VS or did you create controls by hand ?) visual designer properties editor: `if ( totalChips.Text == "" )` or if you want to be scrupulous you can write `if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(totalChips.Text) )` ?

Comment: Thanks (string.IsNullOrEmpty(totalChips.Text) worked. And yes I used VS

Comment: "All this code is under the form_Load event." then you should need only to change your if condition to : `if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(totalChips.Text))`

Comment: Use `ApplicationSettings->PropertyBinding`. Bind the Text of your Label to the `SaveCoins` setting (must be string) and you're done. All automatic.

Comment: Test with e.g., `Properties.Settings.Default.SaveCoins = 10.ToString();`. You'll see that the Label's text changes immediately. If you call `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`, the next time your Form opens, the `totalChips.Text` will be `"10"`.

Answer (score 0):

I used if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(totalChips.Text)) to set the first time launch is zero and afterwords the else is called and I just called the method to get the saved value before calling the if statement.

```
        totalChips.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.SaveCoins;
        EnableRedeem.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.SaveRedeem;

        if (totalChips.Text == "")
        {
            totalChips.Text = "0";
            Properties.Settings.Default.SaveCoins = totalChips.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
        else
```